# Invoking an earlier version of python in cmd

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.4

I've installed Python 2.7 and python 3.4 on my system. Earlier i was using 3.4 but now require 2.7 as well (for a course I'm taking, which requires some files which are not there for 3.4). When I type python in cmd it by default initializes 3.4. Is there some way to change it to 2.7 by default?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I was able to invoke it using 'py'. Here's the link if anyone else has a confusion. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=shebang#python-launcher-for-windows (from some other answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
If your system environment is **Windows**:

1) call `py -2.7` or `py -3` based on the version you want.

2) change your PATH system environment variable , makes sure it refers to the version you want.

You can do it in serveral ways on **Linux environment**:

1)
call a specific Python binary you can call the explicit full path (e. g. /usr/local/bin/python). This will call the same executable regardless of the value of the $PATH variable.

2)
configure your accounts so that both have the same binary first in the $PATH variable.

3)
call python2 and python3; many installations symlink these to the corresponding binaries.

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: I'm a week old in python so, it'll be really helpful if you could explain a little more, how do I call python2 and python3? Thanks

Comment: just invoke `python2` or `python3` on your terminal

Comment: I've tried that but its not working. Its only responding to python and initiates python 3.4.3.

Comment: what did it say when you type `python2`?

Comment: Thanks, i was able to invoke it using 'py'. Here's the link if anyone else has a confusion. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=shebang#python-launcher-for-windows (from some other answer)

Comment: When i type python2, it gives an error of unrecognised command. Same with python3. I'm able to differentiate using python and py (for 3.4 and 2.7 resp.)

Comment: @pythonnewbie it is my fault. when i saw `my system`, I assumed it is linux environment.  On windows, it is either `py -2` or `py -3`

Comment: '@haifzhan' yes (py-2) and (py -3) seem to work just fine. Thanks a ton :)